# Stripe Refund Prorated on Quantity of Days Subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments

My goal is this: sub service started to experience issues on 11/9. Instead of pausing payments immediately, I let a few weeks go by. I now want to refund the cost incurred to each user based on the prorated cost for the number of days of bad service. So refund each user 19 or 20 days based on their current subscription. Is there a way to do this via API?

It get's so complex with the past month's proration on the bill. It's a nightmare and this would save me so much time. Willing to compensate. Thank you.

I havent been able to try anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can [issue a partial refund by specifying an `amount`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/refunds/create#create_refund-amount) less than the original amount of the payment being refunded using the Stripe API.  You would [specify the `payment_intent`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/refunds/create#create_refund-payment_intent) belonging to the Subscription Invoice in question (which [you can find on the Invoice object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-payment_intent)).

However, you need to calculate the amount you wish to refund on your end based on the amount you want to refund for each Subscription.